# Nested dojo widgets not working

Tags: dojo

I have created a very simple templated widget. Something like this:

```
function (declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, ..., ...) {
    return declare("widgets.some.Widget", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {..

   ...
   templateString: template,
   widgetsInTemplate: true,
   ...
}
```

This widgets loads and works just fine. However, when I want to use it in another templated widget like this:

```
<div style="width: 400px" data-dojo-type="widgets.some.Widget" ... >
</div>
```

.. I end up with 2 errors:

> Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null"

and

> widgets.somewidgetusing.SomeWidget: parser returned unfilled promise
>   (probably waiting for module auto-load), unsupported by
>   _WidgetsInTemplateMixin.   Must pre-load all supporting widgets before instantiation."

Both widgets works great stand alone, but when I use `widgets.some.Widget` in another widget the errors occur.

Comment: Have you included it as a dependency in the other templated widget? Does it work if you replace the dots with slashes?

Comment: Just noticed that using dojo 1.8.5 instead of 1.9.0 eliminates error 2

Comment: It is properly included and now tested with slashes - same errors

Comment: Sorry for posting this too quickly. Problem solved. It turns out a call to domStyle.get(this.domNode.id, "width") from postCreate was the problem. However, domStyle is properly instansiated and the domNode.id exists as it should. I would expect a null return (or something like that) rather than a "dojo-crash"(?)

Comment: @SvenPersson, the widget is not yet in the DOM during postCreate. Put calls that access the DOM in the startup function.

Comment: Could you provide any code in your solution? Would be very helpfuL!

Comment: @MattR Do you see a similar issue here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168372/parser-returned-unfilled-promise-error-in-dojo)? I feel like this is closest post near the same topic.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting this same message. The culprit turned out to be non-unique html ids.  I was nesting some.Widget inside of two different widgets.  Some.Widget's template html has a textbox with `id="Text1"`.  I removed the id and problem resolved.