# 'Parser returned unfilled promise' error in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I'm getting the following error when using `dojo/parser` in my code.

`parser returned unfilled promise (probably waiting for module auto-load), unsupported by _WidgetsInTemplateMixin.`

I've

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "myApp/base/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "dojo/text!../templates/MyTemplate.html",
    "dojo/i18n!../nls/Localized",
    "myApp/js/utils/hint",
    "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox",
    "dijit/form/SimpleTextarea",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dojo/parser",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function (
    declare,
    _WidgetBase,
    _TemplatedMixin,
    _WidgetsInTemplateMixin,
    template,
    l10n,
    hint
) {

    'use strict';

    /**
     * @module
     */

    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {

        widgetsInTemplate: true,

        /**
         * @description Localized object for view
         * @type {object}
         */
        l10n: l10n,

        /**
         * @description Custom template for view
         * @override
         */
        templateString: template,


        //postCreate: function () {
            //hint(l10n.hint);
        //}
    });

});
```

I've done some research and realized it may have to do with dependencies and order. I've added the `widgetsIntemplate` attribute but still no dice. This only happens on first load of the page.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have widgets in your template, you have to make sure they are all preloaded.
Make sure your define has all the widgets in your template.

Comment: Such a simple (but mind-crazy) solution. I thought I checked this a bunch of times before realizing all my elements were in a 'form' element I wasn't declaring. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For future readers: This error message may also be thrown when creating one of the widgets in the template fails to any other reason.

For example I had a `dijit/form/FilteringSelect` in a template and had a typo in the variable I passed to its `store` property. So the store was undefined.

It can be quite hard to find the source of this error message sometimes.

1. Successively remove widgets from the template to identify the one that causes the problem.
2. Instance the widget programatically inside a try-catch block inside your own `buildRendering` function to see what is actually going wrong.